# Django script add field to database

Tags: python, django

I added a slug field to my database and now need to go through and add those. I want to run a script that looks at the slug field in the database and if empty generates and saves. Here is what I thought was along the lines, but is not working.

```
from project.apps.tracks.models import *

def process_slug():  
    if not track.slug:  
        slug = slugify("%s - %s" % (track.name, track.artist)) 
    else:  
        slug = "" 

    super(process_slug, track).save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your posted code it is not evident, that you are actually looping through all your `Track` objects.

```
from project.apps.tracks.models import Track
# import for slugify

def process_slug():
    """ Populate slug field, if they are empty. 
    """
    for track in Track.objects.all():
        if not track.slug:  
            slug = slugify("%s - %s" % (track.name, track.artist)) 
            track.slug = slug
            track.save()
```

One preferred place for such occasionally recurring commands would be under `management/commands` inside your application.

---

Another way to implement would be to override your `Track` model's `save` method. It would check for emtpy slugs on every save (which is not performant).

Comment: If you have backups or don't care about data, try removing the `if` clause, so all rows will be affected.

Comment: Nothing changed by removing if clause. The field is null in the database not blank.

Comment: hard to tell from here, try add logging statements to see what gets actually executed and maybe what not ...

Comment: put print statements in but nothing shows up, add the updated code to the page as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default like this:

```
slug = models.SlugField(default=process_slug)
```